# Sending a retrieved value from fetch to express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
 fetch(apiURL, setting)
     .then(loadRes)
     .then(logger)
```

```
     function loadRes(res){
       console.log("loadRes is called");
       return res.json();
     }
```

```
     function logger(reply){
       stringReply = JSON.stringify(reply);
       //console.log("The JSON String " + stringReply)
       return new Promise(resolve => {
         setTimeout(() => {
           resolve(stringReply);
         }, 2000);
       });
     }
```

```
     async function asyncCall(){
       const result = await logger(reply); // a string value i.e "Hello World"
       console.log(result); //for testing
     }
```

How do I retrieve the value of `stringReply` and place it in the `app.post` from a `Express` module

```
app.post('/', function( req, res){
 res.send(); // 
}
```

When a value is obtained in `function logger(reply)` , I would want it to be able to send it to `res.send()`.

I have tried putting `res.send(asyncCall())` but it does not work.

Whenever I call `asyncCall()`, I would expect a string value.

Comment: `fetch(...).then(loadRes).then(logger).then(jsonString => res.send(jsonString))`

Comment: Why are you delaying the response by 2 seconds?